# Using Facebook Connect in cases where a username or other data is required

Tags: user-interface, facebook

I'm working on a site that requires the user have a unique username to use all services on the site. They cannot self-change this username for community fairness.

We would like to allow users the simplicity of registering/logging in using their facebook accounts, but this username requirement is obviously a hurdle.

The only idea I have come up with is after the connect process, send the user to a final step page where they enter a username. The only downside to this is that the user has the ability to navigate away before entering a username, meaning we need to add further layers of checks to several site functions to ensure a user has a username, and prompt for one if not.

Any ideas on how to streamline this ***during*** the connect process? Any site examples of similar implementations where auxillary info is required to use some or all site features?

Comment: NOTE: Auto-generating usernames or using the person's real name from Facebook is not an option. This is a trading site, so a level of anonymity is required until a trade occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at Facebook's registration plugin?

> The Registration plugin allows users to easily sign up for your
>   website with their Facebook account. The plugin is a simple iframe
>   that you can drop into your page. When logged into Facebook, users see
>   a form that is pre-filled with their Facebook information where
>   appropriate.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/

The plugin also allows you to add custom fields so you could simply add your username field.

There are a load of advanced features including validation, here's an example in the Facebook documentation that includes the username field and checks to see if it's available

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/advanced/#async

Comment: Thanks. I have never seen that and have been reading up on it for the last 30mins or so. One thing that is not really apparent in anything I have read is whether this system links an on-site account with a FB account after the registration (as the current Connect button does). Do you know?

I'm not sure how ideal it will be TBH. It takes a while to load, and if a user is currently logged into Facebook, it pre-enters their information without prompting. That'll freak some users out, and they may not even want to link to Facebook.